# Is there any way to have a step chart and continuous chart in the same chart

Tags: anychart

Is there any way to have a step chart and continuous chart in the same chart, so it would be possibly to have gradual slopes and have a steep drop off, like a step chart.

It would have something that would look like this:[image]

Thanks
David McNulty

Answer (score 0):

There are two possible options.

1. You can use a Cartesian Area chart. Note, that zero points should not have the same timestamp as the top point. Here is [the live sample](https://playground.anychart.com/Zzyh6KzT). Pay attention to the data.
2. Also, you can use the Scatter Line chart. It supports multiple points with the same X-coordinate. So, there's no need to apply a different timestamp to the zero points. Check [the live sample](https://playground.anychart.com/CCAxSSBa).